# Zip Command not found in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, zip

I am trying to zip a directory in a Jenkins pipeline, my code is similar to this

```
stages {
            stage('ZIP') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        currentBuild.displayName = "DISPLAY_NAME"
                    }



                    // Zip DIRECTORY
                    sh '''
                        cd ${WORKSPACE}
                        zip -r zip_file_name src_dir
                        '''
            }
          }
         }
```

I get the following error

> @tmp/durable-4423e1f6/script.sh: line 3: zip: command not found

However, when I create another job with execute as a shell option for the build, zip is working fine.

I have tried using zip pipeline utillity plugin, but when I try to access the zip file it is not found.

```
script {
                        currentBuild.displayName = "${VERSION}"
                         zip zipFile: '${zip_file_name}',   dir: 'src_dir', overwrite: true
                    }
```

Comment: When you are running a zip command via the `sh` step you need zip to be available on the node in which your job is executed. instead you can use the [zip](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file) keyword which is part of the **Pipeline Utility Steps** plugin to achieve what you want.

Comment: Where should the zip be placed in the Jenkinsfile? I tried that I got this error ``` Invalid parameter "zipFile", did you mean "label"? @ line 38, column 25```. Jenkins pipeline utility is installed

Answer (score 2):

@raviTeja, I guess zip utility is missing in your jenkins agent machine. What is the OS flavour of your Jenkins agent? Lets say if you are using Linux flavours like Redhat, ubuntu.. first you need to install the zip utility in the agent machine. Then alone you can use the zip command in your script

If you are using RedHat flavour in the agent machine

1. First install zip utility

```
sudo dnf install zip
```

2. Then execute zip command in your pipeline script

```
zip -r zip_file_name src_dir
```

If you are using ubuntu/debian flavour for jenkins agent

1. Install zip utility using apt

```
sudo apt install zip
```

2. Execute zip command in your pipeline script

```
zip -r zip_file_name src_dir
```

Update:

If you are using Jenkins in the docker container, you can do something similar to the below.

I am guessing you are running ubuntu base image (identify the respective base image Linux flavour and execute the below commands)

1. Get into docker container using exec command

```
docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash
```

2. Update packages

```
apt-get -y update
```

3. Install zip

```
apt-get install zip -y
```

But remember if you delete this container, you are going to loose this set-up. You might have repeat all these steps

Comment: The Jenkins machine has a zip command installed, as I have created another freestyle project with a build step as a shell execution, zip commad worked there. This pipeline is running on a container, could it be because of that, the base image does not come with zip command installed

Comment: Yes.. that might be the reason. In this case, if you are using docker container with dockerfile, I would suggest you can include those zip install commands entries in Dockerfile and build image and start jenkins in container.

Comment: I am using a Docker Image, i dont have the Dockerfile

Comment: @raviTeja Which Linux flavour docker container you are using? You can get into the docker container and execute the respective zip install command. To get into the docker container execute the below command 'docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash'

Comment: I used jenkins pipeline utility plugin , it worked. Thankyou for the help